# SQL Server exception on column name

Tags: sql-server, group-by

When i have a column say "GROUP"

```
TableName.GROUP
```

during select it show me error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'
```

I tried

```
  select [TableName.GROUP] from TableName
```

it shows me `invalid column name TableName.GROUP`

i tried

```
select [dbo.TableName.GROUP] from TableName
```

i received the same error invalid column name `dbo.TableName.GROUP`

I need the column name "GROUP". How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

```
 select [TableName].[GROUP] from TableName
 // or
 select [GROUP] from TableName
```

Comment: or TableName."GROUP", or alias."GROUP", or just "GROUP" if only one table is involved.